# How to do a surface revolution from a line on OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl

I'm trying to generate a surface by rotating a line over Y-axis, but i can't figure how to preserve a matrix to generate new surfaces with the points of the rotate matrix and the previous one.

I've tried to use glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() in many different ways, but didn't figured it out.

This is the function i'm trying to build:

```
void sweepRotacional(){
int i, j;
float theta=PI/4;
float matrizTemp[3][5];
while(theta<2*PI){
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        for(j=0; j<5; j++)
            matrizTemp[i][j] = formaRot[i][j];
    glRotatef(theta, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    generateSurface(matrizTemp);
    theta+= PI/4;
}}
```

The generateSurface() function only generates polygons based on points given by those two matrices, like this:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3f(matrizTemp[0][3], matrizTemp[1][3], matrizTemp[2][3]);
    glVertex3f(formaRot[0][3], formaRot[1][3], formaRot[2][3]);
    glVertex3f(formaRot[0][4], formaRot[1][4], formaRot[2][4]);
    glVertex3f(matrizTemp[0][4], matrizTemp[1][4], matrizTemp[2][4]);
glEnd();
```

So my questions is, can I use matrices like this on OpenGl? If so, how?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are using deprecated features. Please use modern shader-based OpenGL.

Comment: Of course you can use matrices, and your approach is fine, but modern OpenGL uses shaders, written in glsl, a C-like language with builtin matrices and matrix operations.

Comment: I would prefer to use a modern OpenGL approach, but i have an assignment where i'm supposed to use primitive ways "to learn", so I need to find a way of making this work, i may try another approach, but not much different from this one.